# SQL Server - more efficient hashing?

Tags: sql-server, caching, stored-procedures, hash

I am caching data locally from a remote SQL server, and need to know when the remote data has changed so I can update my cache.  The remote data has no modified date column, and I don't have permissions to add columns or create triggers, so there are a lot of options that are closed to me.  My current process is to calculate the checksum of the remote table:

```
select checksum_agg(binary_checksum(*)) from remoteTable;
```

and then if that value changes, I know I need to update my cache.  This basically works, with two flaws:

1. There are lots of changes that woun't cause the checksum to change
2. All I know is "something changed" and I need to copy the entire remote table into my local cache.

In order to be more efficient and more correct, I want to upgrade my process to:

1. Use MD5 hash
2. Return multiple hash values, one for each "chunk" of the output table (in my case, every 10,000 rows) so that I can update only the "chunk" that changed

I've created this stored procedure that relies on the (apparently undocumented) fn_repl_hash_binary function:

```
use dataBase;
if exists (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'GetHash')
    drop procedure GetHash;
create procedure GetHash
as
begin
declare @j int, @x nvarchar(max), @b varbinary(max), @h nvarchar(40)
set @j = 0
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##TempHashTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TempHashTable;
create table ##TempHashTable(id int, xlen int, hash nvarchar(40))
while (@j < 7)
begin
   set @x = (select * from myTable where (id/10000) = @j for xml auto )
   set @b = convert(varbinary(max), @x)
   set @h = convert(char, sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(@b), 2)
   insert into ##TempHashTable(id, xlen, hash) values(@j, len(@x), @h)
   set @j = @j + 1
end
end;
```

This works as expected, the only drawback is it's rather slow.  Checksumming the entire table takes 0.1 seconds (including all the network roundtrip), while "exec GetHash" takes about 0.7 seconds.  That's not bad, but I'm wondering if I can do better.

'id' is the primary key of myTable, so the select should be efficient, what I'm seeing is that the XML being generated is around 2 megabytes for each "chunk", with most of that being repetitive XML tag names and angle brackets.

1. Is there a way to output the values from myTable in a less readable (but more efficient) format than XML?
2. Are there other obvious inefficiencies in my stored procedure that would be causing it to be slow?

---

Yes, there are issues with this stored procedure (like, it only works on one table and I'm assuming the table will always contain fewer than 70,000 rows).  Once I'm happy with the performance I'll put in all the niceties.

---

I just added some timing code, here's what I'm seeing:

- Each "select" is taking about 60 msec
- Calculating each hash is taking about 25 msec

Comment: Hashing can never tell you with certainty if a row (or any collection of rows) changed, simply because rows (usually) have more possible bits than the hash. It's always possible for a row to change, but not its hash (though admittedly, a good hash makes it less likely). Take care that such solutions are never more than approximations, and you will always need some sort of unconditional periodic reload in addition to the hash, no matter how great an interval that reload might have.

Comment: Is replication or log shipping or mirroring an option? I'm assuming you've already checked and discarded these options, but just in case you haven't, they're worth considering before going to solutions like these.

Comment: Oh, add query notifications to the list of things that could solve this without (much) custom code. They're finicky to get right and require that you're allowed to activate Service Broker in the database, but they don't use triggers.

Comment: You are correct that replication and mirroring are not options, the local cache is on SQLite.  Good point on having an unconditional periodic reload ...

Comment: There are a ton of products out there (even open source ones) that provide this functionality (db caching), why reinvent the wheel here?

Comment: (1) cost, (2) not knowing what any of those products are (grin).  Any suggestions on products you've used that are good?